# Convert Case Statement to DAX and M Language Calc

Tags: powerbi

Good Morning

I am trying to get the maximum date for certain description type for each product. I know how to do this SQL but someone can one please guide to write it in DAX.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Product,
MAX(CASE WHEN Description IN ('Toys','Table','Shirts'
AND Type <>'Not Needed' THEN Date END) 
OVER(PARTITION BY  Product) AS XYZ_Date,
MAX(CASE WHEN Description IN ('Soap','Shampoo','Shoes' THEN Date END) 
OVER(PARTITION BY  Product) AS XYZ_Date
FROM TableName
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And be more specific - which language are you trying to use; DAX or M ?

Comment: Hi Olly  I am trying it in DAX

Comment: The please [edit] your question to show what you're trying, and the specific problem you're having. [ask] is worth a read, remembering that this is not simply a code writing service...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest equivalent is IF, e.g.

```
IF ( [Description] IN {"Toys","Table","Shirts"} && [Type] <> "Not Needed" , [Date] )
```

DAX uses C-style boolean operators like && (or functions like AND which are harder to read).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the below calculation but returns max row for all products. Requirement is get max value for each product. Can you please suggest how to achieve this
IF ( [Description] IN {"Toys","Table","Shirts"} && [Type] <> "Not Needed" , max([Date]))

Comment: Output Eg:   
Product Some_ABC_Date Calc I have tried     Desired Result
A 12/03/2019 16/03/2019 15/03/2019
A 13/03/2019 16/03/2019 15/03/2019
            A 15/03/2019 16/03/2019 15/03/2019
B 16/03/2019 16/03/2019 16/03/2019
B 12/03/2019 16/03/2019 16/03/2019
B 14/03/2019 16/03/2019 16/03/2019

Comment: In a Measure, I would use MAXX, e.g. MAXX ( TableName , IF ( [Description] IN {"Toys","Table","Shirts"} && [Type] <> "Not Needed" , [Date]). Then add that and Product to any visual and it will calculate for each Product.

Comment: Thanks Mike. For some reason it gives the maximum date of all products. Below Calculation fixed the issue   ABC_DATE = CALCULATE(MAX([DATE]),
           ALLEXCEPT([Product]),
        Description in {"A","B","C"})

Comment: That looks like you added a Calculated Column, not a Measure? The context works differently.